# An error occurs while adding a custom method to model (from Django tutorial)

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Python and especially to Django. While trying to dive in subj. framework, and run through its official tutorial I got some pain in the neck error which says:

> Attribute error: 'Poll' object has no attribute 'was_published_recently'

I type the next in django shell (invoked by: "python manage.py shell" from projects directory):

> >>> from polls.models import Poll, Choice
>   >>> from django.utils import timezone
>   >>> p = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)
>   >>> p.was_published_recently()

and I get the next shell output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "", line 1, in 
>   AttributeError: 'Poll' object has no attribute 'was_published_recently'"

Can someone help me to get what am I doing wrong here? Because I just have no idea what can lead to such an error... (Already googled inside out the question, but didn't find an answer that could solve my situation).

I use:
Django version 1.5.1
Python version 2.7.5

Here're my "Poll" model code:

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Also, here's my "Admin" file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.models import Choice, Poll

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
    list_display = ('question', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently')

admin.site.register(Choice)
admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

Comment: What is the output when trying `poll.was_published_recently()` in the shell? If that works, have you also restarted the server to pick up the changes in your code?

Comment: I get the next output: "Traceback (most recent call last):  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>    AttributeError: 'Poll' object has no attribute 'was_published_recently'"

Answer (score 2):

make sure you use 4 spaces as indentation instead Tab character, tab makes function does not recognize.

Comment: Wow... fixed it for me. So bizarre... tabbing didn't seem to affect anything else. Was using Sublime Text

Comment: @kenshinji - Please refer to this: http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Tutorial-method-was-published-today-problem-td181333.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that all it is saying is that you haven't included any was_published_recently function in the class.  Thanks for including the admin.py & polls.py files, but I think it's in your models.py file that you need to ensure a couple things.  It looks like you need to make sure that

```
from django.utils import timezone 

def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

are included in your models.py file.